# for loop in bash function

Tags: bash, wildcards, function

I recently wrote the following `bash` function:

```
makeaudiobook () {
count=1
almbumartist=$2
for f in $1; do
        preprocess $f > $f-preprocessed
        text2wave $f-preprocessed -o $f.wav
        lame -b 16 --tt $f --ta $albumartist --tl $albumartist --tn $count $f.wav $f.mp3
        rm -rf $f.wav $f-preprocessed
        count=$(($count+1))
done
}
```

It does not work as expected. It does not iterate over all of the files that fit the glob expression I specify in `$1`. As a one-liner, this would work. An in fact, I made this into a function because I was tired of writing it out as a one-liner. But as a `bash` function, it doesn't work. So what do I need to do to make it work?

I want to be able to call it on things like the output of `split`, like,

```
me@localhost$~ makeaudiobook x?? haskell
```

...where `x??` matches xaa, xab, xac, etc. Like I said, as a one-liner this is fine. So what do I need to do to pass this glob expression to `$1`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`x??` is expanded at the time of function call. So your function is already called with `xaa xab xac`... .

The simplest way would be to change the ordering of your parameters:

```
makeaudiobook () {
count=1
almbumartist=$1
shift
for f in "$@"; do
        preprocess "$f" > "$f"-preprocessed
        text2wave "$f"-preprocessed -o "$f".wav
        lame -b 16 --tt "$f" --ta "$albumartist" --tl "$albumartist" --tn "$count" "$f".wav "$f".mp3
        rm -rf "$f".wav "$f"-preprocessed
        count=$(($count+1))
done
}
```

(look how I put `"` around every variable - this is to prevent bad things from happening if you have whitespace in your file names, what often happens with audio files)

and call it with `makeaudiobook haskell x??`, i. e. with rotated arguments.

Comment: it works! it works!

Comment: Nit: `in "$@"` is redundant. `for <...>; do` by default loops over the parameter array.

Comment: @l0b0 Right (just forgot about that), but IMHO explicit is better than implicit.